# Use Custom UIView as IBOutlet in .xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, iboutlet

I have a custom class inherited from `UIView`

```swift
@interface StatusBarView : UIView

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <ActivationStatusDelegate> delegate;


//MARK: init
- (id) initWithCustom: (struct WidgetCustom *) widget;
- (id) initWithStatus:(ActivationBtnStatus) activeStatus;

//MARK: Function
- (void) setStatus: (ActivationBtnStatus) status;
@end
```

and this is a part of implementation

```swift
@interface StatusBarView ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button2;

- (void) createDefaultWidget;

@end

@implementation StatusBarView

ActivationBtnStatus status = noStatus;
struct WidgetCustom widget;
bool isWidgetSet = false;
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    if (!isWidgetSet) {
        [self createDefaultWidget];
    }
    [self createButton];
}
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {

        [self createDefaultWidget];
        [self createButton];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    CAShapeLayer * maskLayer1 = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer1.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: self.bounds byRoundingCorners: UIRectCornerBottomRight | UIRectCornerTopRight cornerRadii: (CGSize){10.0, 10.}].CGPath;
    CAShapeLayer * maskLayer2 = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer2.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: self.bounds byRoundingCorners: UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerTopLeft cornerRadii: (CGSize){10.0, 10.}].CGPath;

    _button1.layer.mask = maskLayer1;
    _button2.layer.mask = maskLayer2;

}


- (id)initWithCustom:(struct WidgetCustom *) widget {
    self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ActivationStatus" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];

    if (self) {
        isWidgetSet = true;
        widget = widget;
    }

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithStatus:(ActivationBtnStatus)activeStatus {
    self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ActivationStatus" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];

    if (self) {
        status = activeStatus;
    }

    return self;
}
}
```

and this is how I managed the .xib file 
File's Owner's class is empty and there is no outlet for that

[image]

[image]

The outlets are connected to the view instead and I set `StatusBarView` class for the .xib file's view like below

[image]

[image]

Now In different ViewController I want to use this class as an IBOutlet like This without needing any more initialisation: 
[image]

but the result is just a gray view. 
is it possible to such do such things? if yes please tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Its possible but not the way you are doing it. Dont assing to `self` and use the `owner`

Comment: @Sulthan can you explain more? where should I make this change ?

Comment: @taratandel - this looks like a pretty good step-by-step tutorial: https://medium.com/@brianclouser/creating-a-custom-view-using-a-xib-in-objective-c-6041140a16ca  ... If you want to see the buttons / content of your xib when laying out the views in Storyboard, you will also need to implement `IBDesignable`

Comment: @taratandel In short, you cannot load a class `StatusBarView` from the initiazer of `StatusBarView`. Instead, you normally create `self` using `self = [super init...]` and then you load a *view* from the nib and add it as subview of the `StatusBarView` instance. That means that you have to pass `self` as the owner and in the xib the container view will have type `UIView` and the owner will have type `StatusBarView`.

Comment: @DonMag thanks this tutorial was what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading custom views from XIB is not as simple as it would seem to be. I created a custom class for that containing a bunch of convenience methods. So to make this work you have to let your custom view inherit from this class and set `bundle` property for it, also by default your class name should be the same as XIB name

**Interface**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MLSXibLoadingView : UIView

- (instancetype)initWithWidth:(CGFloat)width;

- (instancetype)initWithHeight:(CGFloat)height;

- (instancetype)initWithXibClass:(Class)xibClass;

- (instancetype)initFromXib;

- (instancetype)commonInit;

- (void)setup;

- (void)layoutDone;

- (void)localize;

- (void)update;

- (NSLayoutConstraint *)constraintWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;

- (void)setConstant:(CGFloat)constant forConstraintWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;

@property (nonatomic) NSBundle *bundle;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL layoutIsDone;

@end
```

**Implementation**

```
#import "MLSXibLoadingView.h"


@implementation MLSXibLoadingView

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self = [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self = [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)awakeAfterUsingCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if (!self.subviews.count) {
        return [self commonInit];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (!_layoutIsDone) {
        _layoutIsDone = YES;
        [self layoutDone];
    }
}

- (instancetype)initWithWidth:(CGFloat)width
{
    self = [self commonInitAssigningFrame:NO];
    self.frame = [MLSUtils rect:self.frame scaledToWidth:width];
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithHeight:(CGFloat)height
{
    self = [self commonInitAssigningFrame:NO];
    self.frame = [MLSUtils rect:self.frame scaledToHeight:height];
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithXibClass:(Class)xibClass
{
    return [self commonInitAssigningFrame:NO xibClass:xibClass];
}

- (instancetype)initFromXib
{
    return [self commonInitAssigningFrame:NO];
}

- (instancetype)commonInit
{
    return [self commonInitAssigningFrame:YES];
}

- (void)setup
{
}

- (void)layoutDone
{
}

- (void)localize
{
}

- (void)update
{
}

- (NSBundle *)bundle
{
    return nil; // implement in subclasses
}

- (instancetype)commonInitAssigningFrame:(BOOL)assignFrame
{
    return [self commonInitAssigningFrame:assignFrame xibClass:self.class];
}

- (instancetype)commonInitAssigningFrame:(BOOL)assignFrame xibClass:(Class)xibClass
{
    NSBundle *b = [self bundle];
    assert(b);

    NSString *xibName = NSStringFromClass(xibClass);
    assert([b pathForResource:xibName ofType:@"nib"]);

    MLSXibLoadingView *xibView = [b loadNibNamed:xibName owner:nil options:nil][0];
    xibView.frame = assignFrame ? self.frame : xibView.frame;
    xibView.autoresizingMask = self.autoresizingMask;
    xibView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints;

    for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in self.constraints) {
        id firstItem = constraint.firstItem;

        if (firstItem == self) {
            firstItem = xibView;
        }

        id secondItem = constraint.secondItem;

        if (secondItem == self) {
            secondItem = xibView;
        }

        NSLayoutConstraint *newConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:firstItem
                                                                         attribute:constraint.firstAttribute
                                                                         relatedBy:constraint.relation
                                                                            toItem:secondItem
                                                                         attribute:constraint.secondAttribute
                                                                        multiplier:constraint.multiplier
                                                                          constant:constraint.constant];

        newConstraint.priority = constraint.priority;
        newConstraint.identifier = constraint.identifier;

        [xibView addConstraint:newConstraint];
    }

    return xibView;
}

- (NSLayoutConstraint *)constraintWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
{
    for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in self.constraints) {
        if ([constraint.identifier isEqualToString:identifier]) {
            return constraint;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}

/**
 * Use this method to change constraint constant with given identifier because constraints outlets get invalid
 * after view exchange in commonInitAssigningFrame: method
 */
- (void)setConstant:(CGFloat)constant forConstraintWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
{
    for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in self.constraints) {
        if ([constraint.identifier isEqualToString:identifier]) {
            constraint.constant = constant;
            break;
        }
    }
}

@end
```